# only log certain logs with monolog using a channel in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I'm having a hard time understanding how to configure logging in my symfony app to do what i need to. I don't understand the difference/relationship between handlers and channels. I have the following in my `config.yml`

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        dynamic_request:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_dynamic.log"
            level: debug
```

I then have this defined in my `services.yml`

```
jsonstub.dynamic.response_provider:
    class: ProgrammingAreHard\JsonStub\CoreBundle\Domain\Dynamic\EventListener\DynamicResponseProvider
    arguments:
        - @security.context
        - @logger
        - %kernel.environment%
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onAuthentication }
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: dynamic_request }
```

The desired behavior is for **only** `error` logs to be logged to `%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log` and then i would like to inject a logger into my `DynamicResponseProvider` that logs to `%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_dynamic.log`. The documentation is confusing me. It states the following:

`configuration defines a stack of handlers which will be called in the order where they are defined`

Does this mean that because i have the `dynamic_request` handler defined **any** debug logs will be logged here? That is not my desired behavior. What i would like is that ONLY the `DynamicResponseProvider` will use that handler. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a channel for a handler.
So, if you want that the 'dynamic_request' handler is used only for 'dynamic_request' logs,  your config.yml must be :

```
  dynamic_request:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_dynamic.log"
        level: debug
        channels: dynamic_request
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/channels_handlers.html for more example